# How do I toggle two divs in bootstrap using a tags not buttons at the same time?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, toggle

### This is my toggling link

```
 <li role="presentation"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#shortTermOpt,#longTermOpt" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" >Short Term</a></li>
```

### DIV 1

```
<div  id="shortTermOpt" class="form-group collapse"  style="">
...
</div>
```

### DIV 2

```
<div  class="form-group collapse in" id="longTermOpt" style="">
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of href try to use 
`data-target ="#shortTermOpt,#longTermOpt"`

Comment: Thanks Shleh, It works. I thought that was a button's link only.

Comment: I tried this, but only one of the divs was toggled. So I created two buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use bootstrap multi-collapse `data-bs-target=".multi-collapse"` and `class="collapse multi-collapse"`